# WordPress Multisite - get avatar from parent site

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to access the user avatar from the parent site?

blabla.com = Parent site

me.blabla.com = Subsite (get avatar from blabla.com)

`get_avatar()` only retrieves the avatar from the subsite.

Comment: You might check in WP-admin -> Settings -> Discussion.

Scroll to the bottom "Avatars" section. Under Avatar Display, make sure "Show Avatars" is selected.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question.

Comment: I'm sorry @adamj , maybe this link will help? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_avatar-not-working